# Showing $u \in H^s$ and $\varphi \in C^1$ implies $u\varphi \in H^s$ (product rule)

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be bounded and open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

As a start, I pose this question:

For $u \in H^s(\Omega)=W^{s,2}(\Omega)$, define the Holder seminorm type quantity

$$F(u) = \int_\Omega\int_\Omega\frac{|u(x) - u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}\;\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$
and this integral exists by definition of being in the space $H^s$.

I want to show that if $\varphi \in C^1(\Omega)$ then $F(\varphi u)$ is finite.

How can I do this? can I approximate $\varphi$ by functiosn in $C_c^\infty$ in some way so that i get bounds on $\varphi$ and its derivatiave?

If anyone has a reference for this basic result I would be happy. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that you need some Lipschitz condition on $\varphi$.

Comment: It's $C^1$ so it's locally Lipschit

Comment: Ah so Lipschitz is needed because it means bounded first derivative so the variation term of $\varphi$ is taken care of, right?

Comment: $x \mapsto \tan x$ is smooth, but it is not Lipschitz in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stated form, it is not true. Take $u = 1$, then you would get $F(\varphi) < \infty$ which may not be true if $\varphi$ has some severe singularities at the boundary of $\Omega$.

It does indeed hold for $\varphi \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega) = C^{0,1}(\bar\Omega)$, as pointed out by Siminore. In the cases $s = 0$ and $s = 1$ this is trivial. But I guess also $s \in (0,1)$ is straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks, you mean $\varphi \in$ in the second paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that silly typo.

Comment: Np. Am I right that Lipschitz implies bounded first derivative implies the variation term of $\varphi$ is bounded?

Comment: What do you mean by "variation term of $\varphi$"?

Comment: In the numerator of $F(\varphi u)$, we can add and subtract a term, and we will get a term of the form $|u(x)|^2|(\varphi(x)-\varphi(y))|^2$ and I thought the Lipschitz continuity was used here to bound this as $\leq C|u(x)|^2$

Comment: Yes, you need it there.